# Adding a nav-selected to a dropdown menu for concrete5

Tags: drop-down-menu, styling, concrete5

I am trying to combine two things for a dropdown menu in Concrete5 and just can't seem to make it work and wonder if someone can help me.

I have a this code for the menu

```
    <?
    defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied."));
    $aBlocks = $controller->generateNav();
    global $c;

    if ($c->isEditMode()) {
            echo("<div class=\"menu\" style=\"position:inherit!important;\"><ul>");
    }
    else {
            echo("<div class=\"menu\"><ul>");
    }

    $nh = Loader::helper('navigation');

    foreach($aBlocks as $ni) {
            $_c = $ni->getCollectionObject();
            if (!$_c->getCollectionAttributeValue('exclude_nav')) {

                    $thisLevel = $ni->getLevel();

                    if ($thisLevel > $lastLevel) {
                            echo("<!--[if IE 7]><!--></a><!--<![endif]-->\n<!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->\n<ul>\n");
                    } else if ($thisLevel < $lastLevel) {
                            for ($j = $thisLevel; $j < $lastLevel; $j++) {
                                    echo("</a></li>\n</ul>\n<!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>\n");
                            }
                    }

                    if ($thisLevel == $lastLevel && $i >0) {
                       echo "</a></li>\n";
                    }

                    $pageLink = false;

                    if ($_c->getCollectionAttributeValue('replace_link_with_first_in_nav')) {
                            $subPage = $_c->getFirstChild();
                            if ($subPage instanceof Page) {
                                    $pageLink = $nh->getLinkToCollection($subPage);
                            }

                    }

                    if (!$pageLink) {
                            $pageLink = $ni->getURL();
                    }

                      if ($_c->getCollectionAttributeValue('placeholder')) {
                             $pageLink="javascript:void(0)";
                     }


                    echo '<li><a href="'.$pageLink.'">' . $ni->getName();

                    $lastLevel = $thisLevel;
                    $i++;
            }
    }

    $thisLevel = 0;
    for ($i = $thisLevel; $i <= $lastLevel; $i++) {
            echo("</a></li></ul>");
    }
    echo '</div>';
    ?>
```

but haven't had any luck styling the nav-selected so I wanted to add under the line beginning foreach:

```
    $classes = array();

    if ($ni->isCurrent) {
            //class for the page currently being viewed
            $classes[] = 'nav-selected';
    }

    if ($ni->inPath) {
            //class for parent items of the page currently being viewed
            $classes[] = 'nav-path-selected';
    }
```

from another menu where the nav-selected can be styled but that doesn't make a difference. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or could someone give me a hint how to make this work? I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though you've taken code from two different places and pasted them together (which rarely works). I think your first code sample is from an old template, and the second code sample is from the newer one.

Your best bet here is to start from scratch with the newer, cleaner autonav template:
https://raw.github.com/concrete5/concrete5/master/web/concrete/blocks/autonav/view.php

It shouldn't be too difficult to modify that to do what you want. If you run into trouble with that, try posting as a new question, either here or in the concrete5 forums ( http://concrete5.org/community/forums ).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jordan! I did try that template and couldn't get it to work the way I wanted and that's why I was trying to cobble two things together but thanks for the try anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah, and I get an big error when I use that template in 5.6.0.2. Don't know if that is my problem. I just copied the file as is and loaded into root/autonav/templates. Then I get garbage on the page.